# why the header contains "Content-Type": "Application/Json" will give me 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

when I initialize the http get request. If the header contains "content-type", "application/json", the server will report 500 error. If remove this header, the result is fine. Although the result is json.

Does it related to respond_to ?

Comment: You should include the problem code and details of the error (eg stack trace) in your question: it is too vague at the moment.

Comment: sorry, no server side code, I can only guess right now.

Comment: Are you saying that this problem only happens in production, on your server, and not in development, on your local machine?  You can still add more details of what you're doing.  At the moment i don't think there is enough information for anyone to attempt to answer it.

Comment: I think it's a fair guess that it's related to respond_to with this amount of information, in that there might be a line causing a server error within the json block.  The html format block may just be returning as: :json or something?

Comment: That ought to work. we need more information. Try including your relevant controller code. If you don't have server side code, how could you possibly debug problems in the server side code?